# override nested attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

what happens when I override nested attributes method in rails. For example,

```
class Order
  has_many :line_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items

  def line_item_attributes=(attr)
   # what can I do here.
  end
end

class LineItem
  belongs_to :order
end
```

In the above code ,

1. Inside `line_item_attributes=` method, can I add/modify/delete line items of the order?
2. When is `line_items_attributes=` invoked, if I call `@order.save(params)` ?

Answer (score 9):

### Use an alias

In Rails 4, you can override and call `super`.

In earlier versions, you can use Ruby's `alias`:

```
class Order
  has_many :line_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items

  # order of arguments is new_name, existing_name
  alias :original_line_items_attributes= :line_items_attributes=
  def line_items_attributes=(attrs)
   modified_attributes                 = my_modification_method(attrs)
   self.original_line_items_attributes = modified_attributes
  end

end
```

Comment: I have a special case of this question. The modification I'm getting is just that, the input contains a key like `{ id: 4738979}` which is an id from a non rails system, referred to internally as `public_id`. So I do this: `attrs[:id] = LineItems.where(public_id: attrs[:id]).first.id`... This isn't very elegant, and I'm almost certain that rails has a way of doing this for me. Any thoughts? (_for now I'm overriding as you've suggested_)

Comment: May I ask, if I can just build items on my own, and not call `super` at all? Does that `super` provide any other magic than just building items?

Answer (score 8):

1. Yes you could. Just call

`assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association(:line_items, attributes, mass_assignment_options)`

when you're done.

Check the source too: `# File activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb, line 263`

1. From the docs:

> Saving
>
> All changes to models, including the destruction of those marked for
>   destruction, are saved and destroyed automatically and atomically when
>   the parent model is saved. This happens inside the transaction
>   initiated by the parents save method. See
>   ActiveRecord::AutosaveAssociation.

I don't think it's a good idea to overwrite this method. I would add your code to `after_save` hook.

Comment: Wouldn't `super` be a better choice here?

Comment: I assume you mean for the first answer: in this case, no because it creates the method via eval, therefor, if you call super, it would overwrite your method.

Comment: super would be a better choice if it were possible. In edge Rails (Rails 4), you will be able to override a line_item_attributes= setter and call super, but in Rails 3.2.x you currently can't just call super. See https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2945

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem.
Through some effort, I solved the problem.
Maybe someone will meet the same question, so I post the answer here.

`attr_writer` overwrite original setter of `line_items`
Then call super, put the result into default setter

```
class Order
  attr_writer :line_items
  has_many :line_items
  def line_items=(value)
    # manipulate value
    # then send result to the default setter
    super(result)
  end
```